# Can someone explain me why we used curly braces "{}" in this code?

Tags: javascript, iterator, iteration

While I was trying to check how many times an element used in an array, I found this code. It is written by another user and I got it to work but I am trying to figure out why he used "{}" at the end. I know that .reduce() method can get initialValue but I could not understand the use of braces.

```js
var a = ["a","b","b","c","a","b","d"];  
 
 var map = a.reduce(function(obj, b) { obj[b] = ++obj[b] || 1;    
 return obj;
  }, {});
```

I thought that they might be the initialValue parameter since it covers the result, but when I tried to remove the braces the result was not the same. I also checked the MDN documents, found some similar code but could not wrap my mind around it since I am quite new in JavaScript.

When we use the braces I get :

```
{
  a: 2,
  b: 3,
  c: 1,
  d: 1
}
```

But when I remove the braces and run it I get:

```
a
```

I tried using brackets and it resulted as : [ a: 2, b: 3, c: 1, d: 1 ],

So it seems the braces enclose the values but shouldn't it work as usual without braces?

Comment: Documentation: [Array.prototype.reduce() syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Syntax). `arr.reduce(callback[, initialValue])` *"initialValue : Value to use as the first argument to the first call of the callback. If no initial value is supplied, the first element in the array will be used.*"

Comment: `I know that .reduce() method can get initialValue but I could not understand the use of braces.` well, you can understand it if it's `var obj = {}`, this is the same - notation for an object literal. So your initial value would be an empty object.

Comment: "*I thought that they might be the initialValue parameter*" - yes it is. "*but when I tried to remove the braces the result was not the same*" - why did you expect the same result when you changed the call?

Comment: Thank you all for commenting, I did not know that the {} meant an empty object. So I was curious if it had some special function (being an object in this case) or it was just to sort the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The braces `{}` represent a new empty object in javascript, In your case, it will be the object returned by the `reduce` method to the `map` variable, we need to initialize it first then fill it in the core of the `reduce` callback.

> Value to use as the first argument to the first call of the callback. If no initial value is supplied, the first element in the array will be used. Calling **reduce()** on an empty array without an initial value is an error.

It's the **initialValue** take a look to **[reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)**, here's a sample, If you were to provide an initial value as the second argument to reduce(), the result would look like this:

```js
let arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];

arr = arr.reduce((accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex, array) => {
  return accumulator + currentValue;
}, 10);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thank you, I get it. I just started learning about objects, so I did not know what "{}" meant. So when we put {} it means, take these values, process them, and assign them to the variable as an object, right?

Comment: When we do `{}` we initialize the accumulator `obj` with an empty object like `obj={};`, then inside the callback of `reduce` where's filling this object with the processes data.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. It really helped me. I am just starting to learn about objects so I am looking forward to test this tip on my own. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help, Happy coding. (Congratulations, you've earned the **[VoteUp privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)** consider to use it if any answer helps you).

Answer (score 2):

> But when I remove the braces and run it, I get: `a`

This is the [syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Syntax):

```
arr.reduce(callback[, initialValue])
```

> `initialValue` : Value to use as the first argument to the first call of the callback. **If no initial value is supplied, the first element in the array will be used.**"

So, if you use `reduce` without the `initialValue`(`{}`), the first item in the array will be used as the `initialValue` which is `"a"`

So, it becomes similar to:

```js
var a = ["a", "b", "b", "c", "a", "b", "d"];

var map = a.slice(1).reduce(function(obj, b) {
  obj[b] = ++obj[b] || 1;
  return obj;
}, "a");

console.log(map)
```

In the first iteration,

```
obj[b] = ++obj[b] || 1;
```

becomes

```
"a"["b"] = ++"a"["b"] || 1
```

This neither throws an exception, nor does it change the `obj` string. `obj` is still `"a"` and it will be returned every time.

Comment: I see. So I know, .reduce() gets an accumulatorValue and processes it with the currentValue but how does it work in "obj[b] = ++obj[b] || 1;" part? İnitialValue is an empty object. That means reduce will start with an empty object. Means {}[b] = ++{}[b] I guess. But what is the "b" value, I am still trying to figure out. :)

Answer (score 1):

That is the `accumulator` object.You can say that it is the initial value so when the call back function will be executed the initial value will be a empty object.

So in the example below initially it is passing an object which have key `e`

```js
var a = ["a", "b", "b", "c", "a", "b", "d"];

var map = a.reduce(function(obj, b) {
  console.log(obj)
  obj[b] = ++obj[b] || 1;
  return obj;
}, {e:'test'});

console.log(map)
```

Answer (score 1):

The second argument in the `.reduce()` method is the `initialValue`, which is a

> Value to use as the first argument to the first call of the callback. If no initial value is supplied, the first element in the array will be used.

---

**tl;dr**

It's the initial value which `.reduce()` starts with. This is the first argument passed to the callback in the first call.

---

In your case the idea was to build a map of values from the array where keys in the map were the values from the array and values in the map were a number of occurrences of that value in the array.

A map in JS can be easily simulated by an object which in your case has been passed as a literal `{}` to the `.reduce()` method. The method fires the callback for each element in the array passing the result object as the first argument and the current element in the array as the second. But the problem is at the first call - what value should be used as the result object if there were no previous elements in the array to accumulate? That's why you need to pass some initial value to have something to start with. As the MDN states, if no `initialValue` is passed, the first element of the array is used - that's why you got `a` when removed initial value. When you passed `[]` you told JS to have an array literal as the initial value but in the callback, you treat it as an object which is allowed in JS since an array is also an object. The problem arises when you try to iterate over those properties or stringify them using `JSON.stringify()`. But it's for another story ;)

Comment: So we can use .reduce() to process different data types and get different result like in the example. I have seen the use with mathematical operators like reducing an array of number to a single number etc. By using this method I can .reduce() some data and assign it to an object.  Thanks for quick reply!

Answer (score 1):

`{}` create new object if you don't add this then the first element in the array will be used.

You can see that when you run the code with `{}` you get an empty object as the `initialValue` and fulfills your requirement.

```js
var a = ["a","b","b","c","a","b","d"];  
 
var map = a.reduce(function(obj, b) { 
    "use strict";

    if (Object.entries(obj).length === 0 && obj.constructor === Object) {
        console.log("InitialValue is defined as object: ", obj);
    }
    obj[b] = ++obj[b] || 1;    
    return obj;
}, {});

console.log(map);
```

Whereas without `{}` it assigns the first value of array `a` to the `obj` that means now `obj` is a string and when you try to use it as an object then it throws error as in the below code.

```js
var a = ["a","b","b","c","a","b","d"];  
 
var map = a.reduce(function(obj, b) { 
    "use strict";

    console.log("InitialValue not defined: ", obj);
    obj[b] = ++obj[b] || 1;    
    return obj;
});

console.log(map);
```

I have just added `"use strict"` to show this error.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. :) It seems a bir advanced for me, but I understood what you meant.